# Audio loop not working, android HTML5 development with intel XDK

Tags: android, html, loops, audio

need some help.

I'm building an app with HTML5 and using 'Intel XDK' to convert it to an .apk for android. The only issue I'm having is 'Looping' audio files.
I'm using a pretty simple code:

```
 <audio id="myAudio" autoplay loop>
    <source src="sounds/mysound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    <source src="sounds/mysound.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    </audio>
```

When I test the app the sound plays, but only once, no loop.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in Java script in HTML by:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var mp3snd = "songlocation.mp3";
var oggsnd = "home-sound.ogg";

document.write('<audio loop autoplay="autoplay">');
document.write('<source src="'+mp3snd+'" type="audio/mpeg">');
document.write('<source src="'+oggsnd+'" type="audio/ogg">');
document.write('<!--[if lt IE 9]>');
document.write('<bgsound src="'+mp3snd+'" loop="1">');
document.write('<![endif]-->');
document.write('</audio>');

//-->
</script>
```

It will achieve the same effect that you want (playing in background) while still being in HTML 5.

Installing [this](https://github.com/koza/appMobiC2Plugin) plugin might also help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I just copy & pasted the above code, amended the song locations and tested it in Intels XDK and ran the app on my S4. ...unfortunately it's still not working. It's driving me nuts!

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but maybe this will work: <audio autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"> What it seems like however, is not something wrong with the code, but something going wrong with Intel XDX. Do you have the latest version of it?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/koza/appMobiC2Plugin) Installing this plugin might also help. Furthermore, [this](https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=4805&p=17732&hilit=audio+audio+loop#p17732) is a similar problem another user was having, I believe someone in the comments answered it partially.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I have attempted all of the above and still no looping.. The only way around this is to link to a a large mp3 file online, this requires the user to have wifi or 3g, but there's no other way. Thanks again Karma, really appreciate it. Should anyone else find a solution post it here.

Comment: Have you tested the app on any other phone? Perhaps it is specifically not working on that model phone. I'd suggest for you to test it out on other phones or ask someone to test it on their phone. Anyways, good luck with your application.

Comment: I was just thinking about it, and have you tried any other file formats? Such as .wav? If not I would defiantly go and see if they are able to loop or do the same as the mp3.

Answer (score 0):

(Update for issue with XDK Android Sound Loop)

So I've made a compromise that works! Loops when app is running,but it won't run when the phone is locked.. Tested using Intel XDK Android build.

I created an internal IFRAME, that refreshes itself when the sound is over. Example below is a 1 minute sound:

On the page that audio is required:

```
<div id="audio_stream" style="position: absolute; margin-left: -1000px;">
<iframe src="iframes/audiotrack.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

This is the IFRAME code: (location: iframes/audiotrack.html)

```
<!--First, include refresh in meta-->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60;url=audiotrack.html" />
<!--now enter audio that you wish to loop-->
<div id="audio_stream">
<audio controls autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="../sounds/FX/audiotrack.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
</div>
```

So it works, but not in the background. Anyone have any idea on how to keep this playing when the phone is locked?